# Oracle SQL: Adding hours to a date

Tags: sql, oracle

Starting with the date/time of July 20, 2001 10:40:12, display the following result table. Use the Dual table.

- subtract 2 days
  Result :18-jul-01 10:40:12
- add half a day
  Result: 20-jul-01 22:40:12
- add 4and half hours
  Result: 20-jul-01 15:10:12

Comment: What did you try and what result did you get from it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to do your homework for you. *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* - point 3 of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you really have no idea where to start, go back to your tutor and *explain that to them*. Most of them aren't monsters, and do want you to learn. They're familiar with the material they've taught you and may be able to spot the specific gap you're not currently able to make the leap over.

Comment: `Use the Dual table.` - That suggests Oracle and not Sql-Server. Please make sure what database you are working with. Also, please read [ask], focus on the search, research, and show your attempts parts, and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using an Oracle database (based on the mentioning of the Dual table hint), you can do something like this:

```
select to_char(to_date('2001-07-20 10:40:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') - 2, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') from dual;
select to_char(to_date('2001-07-20 10:40:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') + 1/2, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') from dual;
select to_char(to_date('2001-07-20 10:40:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') + 4.5/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') from dual;
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that adding a fraction to a date will in fact add the corresponding fraction of a day to that date. The rest of the code deals with conversion to and from different date formats.